# Garbage bin sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm having a real world problem at work and I was hoping of solving it with python but I can't find the right algorithm to solve it.
Say I have trashcans  with fixed sized holes and I need to throw away a number of specific sized trash bags. Each bag must be specifically in the right size. What algorithm can i use to thro away the trash using the minimum number of  trashcans?

Comment: If the bags come in N different sizes then you need at least N trashcans. The only question is whether you need more than one can for a given size. That seems trivial, just compute how many bags fit in a can. So I don't see the challenge here. Perhaps you should add an example to the question.

Comment: please use `tag` like `python` to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a bin packing or knapsack problem. You should know that both are NP-hard so there are no polynomial time optimal solutions to either problem. However there are a number of heuristic algorithms that are easy to implement that can guarantee "near" optimal solutions.

The most well known are First Fit an Best Fit. Both of these algorithms are guaranteed to pack items into bins such that the number of bins used is not greater than 1.7x the number of bins that would be used in an optimal solution. You can read more about these algorithms [here](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs130b/BinPacking.txt).

A very simple example using first fit in python might look like this:

```
import random

bin_capacity = 1.0
bins = [[]]
bin_stats = [0.0] # used to keep track of how full each bin is
jobs = [random.uniform(0.0,1.0) for i in range(100)]
for job in jobs: # iterate through jobs
    job_assigned = False
    for i in range(len(bin_stats)):
        if job + bin_stats[i] <= bin_capacity:
            # if job will fit into bin, assign it there
            bins[i].append(job)
            bin_stats[i] += job
            job_assigned = True
            break
    if not job_assigned:
       # if job doesn't fit into any bin, open a new bin
       bins.append([job])
       bin_stats.append(job)

for i in range(len(bins)):
    print "Bin {:} is {:.2f}% full and contains the following jobs".format(i,bin_stats[i]*100)
    for job in bins[i]:
        print "\t",job
```

Comment: Well I'll give more info. I'm have some equipment to test. Some of my testing equipment has say 3 usb ports and 5 Ethernet ports and another testing devics that has 1 usb port an 8 ethernets and a serial port. And so on...